# SwiftUI view referenced from model fails to update

Tags: swiftui

When I try this code, the rectangle isn't updated when I press the Move cursor button below. It works as expected when used directly, without a model. Why is this?

```
class TestZStackModel {
    var view: TestZStackView! = nil
    func setRect() {
        view.cursorRect = CGRect(x: CGFloat.random(in: 0 ... 100), y: CGFloat.random(in: 0 ... 100), width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
struct TestZStackView: View {
    @State var cursorRect: CGRect = .zero
    let model: TestZStackModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Canvas { graphics, size in
                    print("redrawing canvas")
                    graphics.stroke(
                        Path(ellipseIn: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)),
                        with: .color(.green),
                        lineWidth: 4)
                }
                Rectangle()
                    .position(x: cursorRect.midX, y: cursorRect.midY)
                    .frame(width: cursorRect.width, height: cursorRect.height)
            }
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            Button(action: {
                model.setRect()
            }, label: { Text("move cursor") })
        }
    }
}

func makeZStackView() -> some View {
    let model = TestZStackModel()
    let view = TestZStackView(model: model)
    model.view = view
    return view
}
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        makeZStackView()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

The rectangle in the cursorRect @State field should cause the view to update the Rectangle in the ZStack.

Answer (score 0):

Before I address the main topic, there are a few points I would like to mention.

- The ViewModel is responsible for storing and managing data
- The ViewModel **DOES NOT** hold any view object
- The view interacts with the ViewModel by making changes to the data it holds
- As the data is bound to the view, any changes made to the `ViewModel` will rerender the respective view graph

Now make changes to your code in the following way.

```swift
class TestZStackViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var cursorRect: CGRect = .zero
    func setRect() {
        cursorRect = CGRect(x: CGFloat.random(in: 0 ... 100),
                            y: CGFloat.random(in: 0 ... 100),
                            width: 100,
                            height: 100)
    }
}

struct TestZStackView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: TestZStackViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Canvas { graphics, size in
                    print("redrawing canvas")
                    graphics.stroke(
                        Path(ellipseIn: CGRect(origin: .zero,
                                               size: size)),
                        with: .color(.green),
                        lineWidth: 4)
                }
                Rectangle()
                    .position(x: model.cursorRect.midX,
                              y: model.cursorRect.midY)
                    .frame(width: model.cursorRect.width,
                           height: model.cursorRect.height)
            }
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            Button(action: {
                model.setRect()
            }, label: { Text("move cursor") })
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TestZStackView(model: TestZStackViewModel())
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,
                   maxHeight: .infinity)
            .padding()
    }
}
```